# How to write data into a .SLK File

Tags: text-processing

I have a very simple ETL job - a simple file conversion from .txt to another. Five minutes, right? Well, except for one thing - the output file needs to be .SLK.

I Googled a bit and it seems to be a "programmed" format, with format data embedded into the file itself. Anybody have any links regarding the details of the format? Help me out here, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.SLK is the file extension but what you want is probably better known as "SYLK" format.  It can be generated using only ASCII text. An overview of the format is here: http://hernk.wordpress.com/2007/06/23/the-sylk-file-format/

And here's is a program that generates SYLK files, although it's probably is not usable for your purposes since your source is a .TXT file rather than an an Oracle database: [PL/SQL program at asktom.oracle.com](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:728625409049).  From that link, SYLK files offer "... the ability to do much fancier stuff like fonts, headings, formulas and such."

Comment: Oh, I'd already solved this after some more googling and saving some spreadsheets in .SLK and inspecting the underlying ASCII text. I'm now the proud owner of a datastage job that creates weekly SLK-formatted reports for my client. But thanks anyway! :-)